# Missing split labels in ldply (plyr)

Tags: r, plyr

Why is the split labels missing when we use ldply or adlply. An example would be this:

```
 ldply(c(200,300), function (x) data.frame(ab = rnorm(5, x, 3), cd = rnorm(5, x+5, 6)) )
```

This produces the following data frame.

```
      ab       cd
1  199.4157 204.2111
2  196.3539 199.8178
3  200.1344 206.8755
4  199.5139 203.1514
5  205.3079 211.6156
6  300.5455 301.9101
7  298.5198 303.3942
8  296.8209 309.0427
9  300.9115 296.7305
10 302.0099 305.9254
```

What I wanted is the following data.frame.

```
   .id    ab       cd
1  200  199.4157 204.2111
2  200  196.3539 199.8178
3  200  200.1344 206.8755
4  200  199.5139 203.1514
5  200  205.3079 211.6156
6  300  300.5455 301.9101
7  300  298.5198 303.3942
8  300  296.8209 309.0427
9  300  300.9115 296.7305
10 300  302.0099 305.9254
```

Why is plyr not setting split labels anymore? I did this using adply but does the same.

Comment: i dont use plyr et al, but why not do it manually...change to  `data.frame(id=x, ab = ... `

Comment: I want it to be automated and reduce the coding lines.

Comment: Fair enough, although i think this will be slightly less coding than creating a named input vector, but tomatoes tomaetoes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the documentation of `ldply`:

> **.id**
>   name of the index column (used if .data is a named list). Pass NULL to avoid creation of the index column. For compatibility, omit this argument or pass NA to avoid converting the index column to a factor; in this case, ".id" is used as colum name.

So, in order for this to work you could provide a named list as the first argument of `ldply`. Something like this:

```
ldply(list('200'=200,'300'=300), function(x) data.frame(ab = rnorm(5, x, 3), 
                                                        cd = rnorm(5, x+5, 6)))
```

And this way you can get your id column:

```
> ldply(list('200' = 200, '300' = 300), function (x) data.frame(ab = rnorm(5, x, 3), cd = rnorm(5, x+5, 6)) )

   .id       ab       cd
1  200 199.5737 206.9272
2  200 195.1648 209.4860
3  200 201.3358 207.6002
4  200 206.5642 211.2661
5  200 200.7969 194.2578
6  300 300.1042 311.7641
7  300 297.6136 292.2191
8  300 301.4618 302.5053
9  300 303.0787 299.6548
10 300 298.1153 302.7402
```